# PySpark - pass a value from another column as the parameter of spark function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe which looks like this where expr is SQL/Hive filter expression.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|expr                     |var1     |var2 |
+-------------------------+---------+-----+
|var1 > 7                 |9        |0    |
|var1 > 7                 |9        |0    |
|var1 > 7                 |9        |0    |
|var1 > 7                 |9        |0    |
|var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |
|var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |
|var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |
|var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |
|var1 = 2 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |
+-------------------------+---------+-----+
```

I want to transform this dataframe to the dataframe below where flag is the boolean value found after evaluating the expression in column 'expr'

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|expr                     |var1     |var2 |flag     |
+-------------------------+---------+-----+---------+
|var1 > 7                 |9        |0    |  True   |
|var1 > 7                 |9        |0    |  True   |
|var1 > 7                 |9        |0    |  True   |
|var1 > 7                 |9        |0    |  True   |
|var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |     .   |
|var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |     .   |
|var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |     .   |
|var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |     .   |
|var1 = 2 AND var2 >= 0   |9        |0    |     .   |
+-------------------------+---------+-----+---------+
```

I have tried using expr function like this:

```
df.withColumn('flag', expr(col('expr')))
```

It will fail as expected because expr function expects a string as parameter.

Another idea I thought of using is making a UDF and passing the 'expr' column's value to it, but that will not allow me to use the expr function of pyspark because UDFs are all non-spark code.

What should my approach be? Any suggestions please?

Comment: Short answer you can do this but with a window function. Can you explain the bigger problem you're trying to solve or upload a better sample data i.e. one with a column to groupby

Comment: how can you do this using window function @Dee . I think UDF is the only solution. Mappartition will be anothe solution and may be more fast

Comment: I need the OP to explain what the real data is like or what the bigger problem that this is solving

Comment: @Manish for now checkout my answer

Comment: @Dee Assume that I have two dataframes, one with all the real data and another one with all filter rules (as stated above) to apply to the real data. For each of the row in the first dataframe, only one of the filter rules will be true upon which further values will be derived for that row. To do this, what I'm doing is taking a cross join (which is the dataframe I showed in the example above) between the 2 dataframes and then trying to evaluate each of the rules for each row. Let me know if the explanation is clear?

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, that is a nice problem to solve. I'll update my answer now with a slightly more efficient solution but both with give your desired output, so could you mark is as the correct answer?

Comment: @Dee done, marked your answer as the correct answer! Answer using coalesce is extremely efficient :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's a PySpark solution without a UDF. In Scala I believe you could use map or foldleft with the same logic.

```
exprs = df.select('expr').distinct().collect()[0][0]

for ex in exprs:
    df = df.withColumn('test', when(col('expr') == lit(ex), expr(ex)))
    
df.show()
```

```
+--------------------+----+----+----+
|                expr|var1|var2|test|
+--------------------+----+----+----+
|            var1 > 7|   9|   0|true|
|            var1 > 7|   9|   0|true|
|            var1 > 7|   9|   0|true|
|            var1 > 7|   9|   0|true|
|var1 = 3 AND var2...|   9|   0|null|
|var1 = 3 AND var2...|   9|   0|null|
|var1 = 3 AND var2...|   9|   0|null|
|var1 = 3 AND var2...|   9|   0|null|
|var1 = 2 AND var2...|   9|   0|null|
+--------------------+----+----+----+
```

I should point out that I don't understand why the OP wants to do this, if they provide better context to the problem I'm sure there's a better way.

Iterating over a DF isn't the most efficient thing to do, but in this case it will actually work very fast as it doesn't iterate over the data so Spark will actually execute it within one plan. Also a single collect() only adds 2 seconds to the execution time on a 20+ million DF.

---

UPDATE:

I understand the problem a bit better now, this will be faster as Spark will calculate all of the filters at once before coalescing them into one column.

```py
# Tip: perform the collect statement on the smaller DF that contains the filter expressions

exprs = df.select('expr').distinct().collect()[0][0]

df = df.withColumn('filter',
              coalesce(*[when(col('expr') == lit(ex), expr(ex)) for ex in exprs])
             )
df.show()
```

```py
+--------------------+----+----+------+
|                expr|var1|var2|filter|
+--------------------+----+----+------+
|            var1 > 7|   9|   0|true  |
|            var1 > 7|   9|   0|true  |
|            var1 > 7|   9|   0|true  |
|            var1 > 7|   9|   0|true  |
|var1 = 3 AND var2...|   9|   0|null  |
|var1 = 3 AND var2...|   9|   0|null  |
|var1 = 3 AND var2...|   9|   0|null  |
|var1 = 3 AND var2...|   9|   0|null  |
|var1 = 2 AND var2...|   9|   0|null  |
+--------------------+----+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

not udf

```
  val exprs5 =   sourceDF.select('expr).distinct().as[String].collect()
  val d1 = exprs5.map(i => {
    val df = sourceDF.filter('expr.equalTo(i))
    df.withColumn("flag", expr(i))
  })
  val d2 = d1.reduce(_ union _)
```

udf

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object Filter extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val sourceDF = Seq(("var1 > 7", 9, 0),
  ("var1 > 7", 9, 0),
  ("var1 > 7", 9, 0),
  ("var1 > 7", 9, 0),
  ("var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0", 9, 0),
  ("var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0", 9, 0),
  ("var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0", 9, 0),
  ("var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0", 9, 0),
  ("var1 = 2 AND var2 >= 0", 9, 0)).toDF("expr", "var1","var2")

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val fCheck = udf((expr: String, val1: Int, val2: Int) => {
    expr.split(" ") match{
      case Array(vr, z, vl) if (vr == "var1" && z == ">") => Some(val1 > vl.toInt)
      case Array(vr1, z1,  vl1, logic1, vr2, z2, vl2)
        if (vr1 == "var1") && (z1 == "=") && (logic1 == "AND") && (vr2 == "var2") && (z2 == ">=")
      => Some((val1 == vl1.toInt ) && (val2 >= vl2.toInt))
      case _ => None
    }
  })

  val resultDF = sourceDF.withColumn("flag", lit(fCheck('expr, 'var1, 'var2)))

  resultDF.show(false)
//  +----------------------+----+----+-----+
//  |expr                  |var1|var2|flag |
//  +----------------------+----+----+-----+
//  |var1 > 7              |9   |0   |true |
//  |var1 > 7              |9   |0   |true |
//  |var1 > 7              |9   |0   |true |
//  |var1 > 7              |9   |0   |true |
//  |var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0|9   |0   |false|
//  |var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0|9   |0   |false|
//  |var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0|9   |0   |false|
//  |var1 = 3 AND var2 >= 0|9   |0   |false|
//  |var1 = 2 AND var2 >= 0|9   |0   |false|
//  +----------------------+----+----+-----+

}
```